# adjusting image brightness with slider

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

For windows phone app, when I am adjusting brightness by slider it works fine when I move it to right. But when i go back to previous position, instead of image darkening, it goes brighter and brighter. Here is my code based on pixel manipulation.

private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

```
    wrBmp = new WriteableBitmap(Image1, null);


    for (int i = 0; i < wrBmp.Pixels.Count(); i++)
    {
        int pixel = wrBmp.Pixels[i];
        int B = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
        int G = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
        int R = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
        int A = (int)(pixel);

        B += (int)slider1.Value; R += (int)slider1.Value; G += (int)slider1.Value;
        if (R > 255) R = 255; if (G > 255) G = 255; if (B > 255) B = 255;
        if (R < 0) R = 0; if (G < 0) G = 0; if (B < 0) B = 0;
        wrBmp.Pixels[i] = B | (G << 8) | (R << 16) | (A << 24);
    }
    wrBmp.Invalidate();
    Image1.Source = wrBmp;

}
```

what am i missing and is there any problem with slider value. I am working with small images as usual in mobiles

Comment: hey kookiz,its a duplicate of adjusting image brightness.Beac